# Print several string patterns into one single line in console

Tags: java

I am trying to print out numbers with # character drawing representation to the console. However, when I try to input two numbers, for example, they are printed out below each other not next to each other.

```
static void print(int mat[][])
{
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
                if (i % 2 == 0) {
                    if (mat[i][j] == 1)
                        System.out.print("#");
                    else
                        System.out.print(" ");
                }
                else {
                    if (mat[i][j] == 1)
                        System.out.print("#");
                    else
                        System.out.print(" ");
                }
            }
            System.out.println();
        }

}
```

A matrix for the 5 number digit is defined as below:

```
    int mat[][] = { { 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 },
                    { 1, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
                    { 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 },
                    { 0, 0, 0, 0, 1 },
                    { 1, 1, 0, 1, 1 } };
```

The screenshot below is the output when I try to input 55 to my program (Expected output is to draw both digits next to each other with a space between them):

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure why you expect the two '#' numbers to be beside eachother. There's nothing in this code indicating that that's the intended output, did you write this yourself or are you working off of existing code?

Comment: If you want to print side by side, your "j" should go until the iterator is less than 11 or 12(If you also want to put space between two digits.) and you will need to handle j in mod 5 in that case since your matrix is 5x5.

Comment: @EwanBrown I have wrote this based on a code, but not exactly the same. I have tried to use StringBuilder to append results but I still did not get the desired output which I want to display them next to each other.

Comment: how does your expected output look like? any example?

Comment: @sittsering the output screenshoot is the actual output of my code. I want them to be printed out next to each other like this 55 (not below each other).

Comment: @AbdurrahmanYavuz would you please clarify more? in the  inner loop J should be < 12?  This will throw an exception because each number matrix is a 5X5

Comment: @Androider is that method only for printing 5? like 5 or 55 or 5555? any other number?

Comment: @Androider but, your matrix represents the number 5, not 55. If you want to print the same number two times side by side you will need either need to traverse the matrix two times.  Also, I do not understand why the matrix element (5,3) is zero.

Comment: I don't think any compiler can "go to the precious line" when outputing to the console. I might be wrong. This means that you either stick to the output being vertical or, as implied by @AbdurrahmanYavuz , you write not a matrix per digit but a matrix for the number.

Comment: @sittsering Any number from 0 to 9. I have seperate matrix for each number .

Comment: @AbdurrahmanYavuz I don't want to print the same number two times. The program takes the input from standard input and I extract each number from the input and call that print function in my post for each number in the output (So if the input is 9632, my print method will be called 4 times).

Comment: Instead of printing all rows of a single digits, you need to print the first row of the first digit, then spaces, then the first row of the second digit, and so on, for all the digits you intend to print (as in your example of 9632). Only then would you print a newline and move on to the second row of all digits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```java
public class Main {

    public static void main(String... args) {
        print("0123456789");
    }

    private static final String[][] DIGITS = {
            { "#####", "    #", "#####", "#####", "#   #", "#####", "#    ", "#####", "#####", "#####" },
            { "#   #", "  # #", "    #", "    #", "#   #", "#    ", "#    ", "    #", "#   #", "#   #" },
            { "#   #", "#   #", "#####", "#####", "#####", "#####", "#####", "    #", "#####", "#####" },
            { "#   #", "    #", "#    ", "    #", "    #", "    #", "#   #", "    #", "#   #", "    #" },
            { "#####", "    #", "#####", "#####", "    #", "#####", "#####", "    #", "#####", "    #" } };

    public static void print(String val) {
        for (int row = 0; row < DIGITS.length; row++) {
            for (int i = 0; i < val.length(); i++) {
                if (i > 0)
                    System.out.print(' ');

                int digit = Character.getNumericValue(val.charAt(i));
                System.out.print(DIGITS[row][digit]);
            }

            System.out.println();
        }

        System.out.println();
    }

}
```

Output:

```
#####     # ##### ##### #   # ##### #     ##### ##### #####
#   #   # #     #     # #   # #     #         # #   # #   #
#   # #   # ##### ##### ##### ##### #####     # ##### #####
#   #     # #         #     #     # #   #     # #   #     #
#####     # ##### #####     # ##### #####     # #####     #
```

Comment: This looks working perfectly. I wonder if the string input contains a seperator character (e.g. a ":" like in time 09:32). I need to add that : repsesntation to the DIGITS array then what needs to be edited in your solution?

Comment: @Androider yes. In case of **any** symbol, you can use e.g. `Map` instead of  an array

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code that does what you want to do. But I think there should be another way around to obtain a more generic way.

```
    static void matPrint(int mat[][])
{
    int n = 10  ; // How many times you want to print side by side?
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < (mat[0].length*n)+(n-1); j++) {
            if(j%6==5 && j!=0) {
                System.out.print(" ");
                continue ;
            }
                if (i % 2 == 0) {
                    if (mat[i][j%(mat[0].length+1)] == 1)
                        System.out.print("#");
                    else
                        System.out.print(" ");
                }
                else {
                    if (mat[i][j%(mat[0].length+1)] == 1)
                        System.out.print("#");
                    else
                        System.out.print(" ");
                }
            }
            System.out.println();
        }

}
```

Comment: Thanks. I have tried your answer, it outputs a close answer. Now when I input in console 55, the output is:
55
55

Which means it prints out the two numbers next to each other (but two times vertically also).

Comment: also I still can't print out more than two numbers next to each other.

Comment: You are welcome. I do not see any reason for it to print two times vertically, please delete the code after you use my function matPrint and let me know if the problem persists.

Comment: @Androider It's as David says, you have to print first row of all the numbers, then move to new line and print the 2nd row of all numbers, then move to 3rd row, and so on. You can't print one number and then print other numbers right next to it because it'll move to new line. Another way of doing it is with gui which is much different

Comment: It sounds like you should put the results into a string first, then print the string at the end.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest using 3d array.

```
int mat[][][] = 
                {
                    {   //insert 0th pattern and followed by 1 to 9.
                        { 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 },
                        { 1, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
                        { 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 },
                        { 0, 0, 0, 0, 1 },
                        { 1, 1, 0, 1, 1 } 
                    },
                    {   
                        { 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 },
                        { 1, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
                        { 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 },
                        { 0, 0, 0, 0, 1 },
                        { 1, 1, 0, 1, 1 } 
                    }
                };
int num = // user input;
print(mat,num);
```

```
static void print(int mat[][][],int num)
{
    int len = Integer.toString(num).length();
    int arr[] = new int[len];
    for(int i=len-1;i>=0;i--)
    {
        arr[i] = num%10;
        num = num/10;
    }
    // above are for splitting the num into array.
    // 5483 to {5,4,8,3}
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        for(int k = 0;k < len;k++){
            // this for-loop is for iterating one row of all the numbers
            // 1st row of 5, 4, 8, 3 and then 2nd row and so on.
            for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
                if (mat[arr[k]][i][j] == 1)
                    System.out.print("#");
                else
                    System.out.print(" ");
            }
            System.out.print("  ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Comment: @Androider try applying this method and check if it works

Comment: I get the following exception: ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 9 out of bounds for length 2

Comment: have you added the pattern in 3d array properly? which line did you get the error from?

Comment: someone posted a better solution, you can go with that